# Как отобразить легенду в matplotlib для диаграммы тип bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Необходимо отобразить в легенде все значения x. По факту получаю, только первый элемент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ожидаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При построении диаграммы типа pie (с такими же параметрами), легенда отображается правильно.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"]
y = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

color_rectangle = np.random.rand(7, 3)    # RGB
ax.bar(x, y, color=color_rectangle)

fig.set_figwidth(12)
fig.set_figheight(6)
fig.set_facecolor('floralwhite')
ax.set_facecolor('seashell')
ax.legend(x)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого типа графиков вам нужно получить хендлеры, чтобы к ним привязать легенду:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"]
y = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figwidth(12)
fig.set_figheight(6)
fig.set_facecolor('floralwhite')

color_rectangle = np.random.rand(7, 3)    # RGB
bars = ax.bar(x, y, color=color_rectangle, label=x) # получаем график в переменную


ax.set_facecolor('seashell')
ax.legend(bars, x) # указываем хендлеры и метки к ним

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]